# bind9 with 'dnssec-policy default;' does not update zonerecords when signing

Tags: named, bind9, dnssec

I'm running `bind9` on ubuntu 20.04, package version is `1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.11`. I've configured it to do fully automatic DNSSEC signing, using the `dnssec-policy default;` statement in zone configuration.

I have a few zones setup, but they don't seem to update properly. When I update (or remove) a record from the original unsigned zonefile, and then run `rndc sign example.com`, I see in the logs that a new serial is generated, the zone is signed, and the updated zone is transferred to the slave servers:

```
named[638]: received control channel command 'sign example.com'
named[638]: zone example.com/IN (signed): reconfiguring zone keys
named[638]: zone example.com/IN (signed): next key event: 30-Oct-2022 21:36:42.061
named[638]: zone example.com/IN (signed): sending notifies (serial 2022020430)
named[638]: client @0x7f132004b0a0 1.2.3.4#44170 (example.com): transfer of 'example.com/IN': IXFR started (serial 2022020429 -> 2022020430)
named[638]: client @0x7f132004b0a0 1.2.3.4#44170 (example.com): transfer of 'example.com/IN': IXFR ended: 1 messages, 12 records, 1093 bytes, 0.001 secs (1093000 bytes/sec)
```

But when I inspect the updated zone, either by querying the servers (primary or secondaries, makes no difference) or inspecting the signed zonefile on disk on the master using `named-checkzone -D -f raw example.com example.com.signed`, my changes have not been applied.

The serial is updated just fine, but my records are still the old ones. Updated records don't show up, removed records keep showing up.

When I remove generated files from the server (example.com.jbk, example.com.signed, example.com.signed.jnl), they come back after `rndc sign`, or some time later without me doing something (maybe the server scheduled tasks for later?). And some later, the zone actually gets updated to my liking. But apparently I need forcibly remove files from the server?

I have no idea how to make bind use my updated zonefile to generate a signed zonefile with correct contents without pulling weird tricks. Maybe someone can explain what is going on?

NB I've set this up using the [DNSSEC guide](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_16_33/dnssec-guide.html#signing) from the bind9 docs. In [newer versions of that document](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dnssec-guide.html#easy-start-guide-for-signing-authoritative-zones), it's stated that I need to add `inline-signing yes;` to my zone configuration, but that results in an error (`inline-signing: cannot be configured if dnssec-policy is also set`). So that is not the solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

The problem was that I was using `rndc sign example.com` to push updates out. the `sign` command just resignes the existing (in-memory) data.

After editing the unsigned domain file on disk, you need to use `rndc reload example.com` to instruct `named` to read the updated zonefile. Then it will automatically resign the zone, send notifies etc. Don't forget to increase the serial in the zonefile, otherwise `named` will reject the update (but this will only be visible in the logs, not in the response to your `rndc` command).